# How to avoid using global variables when using windows.h C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, switch-statement, global-variables

So I've got the following code and I really have two questions:

How can I avoid using global variables to store information for
    later use? I obviously cannot add more parameters to WndProc or
    change the return type. What else can I do to store new information
    for later?

Why can't I use the `LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs = reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam);
vector<string> *strings = reinterpret_cast<vector<string>*>(lpcs->lpCreateParams);` 
code outside of the switch statement and then refer to the pointer to the vector of strings inside the switch statement? I don't understand why it is out of scope when I do this (I also don't use switch statements very often). I also tried declaring a `size` variable outside the switch statement to store the length of the vector after it was declared inside the switch statement but of course I ran into the same problem.

```
void Select(vector<string>& ret)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL); //NULL = the current process
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    MSG  msg;

    wc.lpszClassName = L"Selection1";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Selection",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, hInstance, &ret);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    bool checked = true;
    HWND text, button;
    //hwnd is parent window
    switch (msg) {

case WM_CREATE: {
    text = CreateWindow("STATIC", "Selection:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 20, 20, 300, 25, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Exit", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 500, 500, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)0, NULL, NULL);
    LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs = reinterpret_cast<LPCREATESTRUCT>(lParam);
    vector<string> *strings = reinterpret_cast<vector<string>*>(lpcs->lpCreateParams);
    int j = 23;
    checkVectorSize = strings->size(); //checkVectorSize is a global variable
    for (int i = 1; i != strings->size() + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << (*strings)[i - 1].c_str() << endl;
        CreateWindowA("button", (*strings)[i - 1].c_str(),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX | WS_OVERLAPPED,
            20, j, 185, 35, hwnd, (HMENU)i,
            NULL, NULL);
        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, 0, BST_UNCHECKED);

        j = j + 25;
    }


    break;
}
case WM_COMMAND: {
    int i = wParam;
    if (i == 0) //LOWORD(wParam)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j != checkVectorSize; j++)
        {
            if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, j + 1) == true)
            {
                checkResultIndexes.push_back(j);
                //GetClassName(hwnd,)
                //checkResult.push_back();
            }

        }
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
        //::MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
        //::MessageBox(hwnd, "Button was clicked", "", MB_OK);
        break;
    }
    checked = IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, i);
    if (checked) {

        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, i, BST_UNCHECKED);
        SetWindowTextW(hwnd, L"");
    }
    else {
        CheckDlgButton(hwnd, i, BST_CHECKED);
        SetWindowTextW(hwnd, L"");
    }
    break;
}
case WM_DESTROY: {

    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
}
}
return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

Comment: How do you call `Select`? Will the vector you pass a reference to be desctructed once the callback for `WM_CREATE` is called? Perhaps you should try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: "I  also don't use switch statements very often" - if you intend to use Win32, better read up on them. Of course, the real solution is not to us Win32 - if you want to create Windows GUI aplixations, use C#.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy My program always throws an exception when I do that "read access violation".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude When WM_CREATE is called, the elements of the vector will be used to name the individual checkboxes.

Comment: I'll never understand all the downvotes I get on this site lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Get` / `SetWindowLongPtrW` with `GWLP_USERDATA` flag to associate arbitrary data with a window. In `WM_CREATE` handler:

```
SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpter_cast<::LONG_PTR>(strings));
```

To retrieve stored value later:

```
vector<string> *strings = reinterpret_cast<vector<string>*>(GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
assert(strings);
```

Note that you must ensure that object this pointer points to survives for long enough.

Comment: So the 4th argument can be any arbitrary data? Is there any way to be able to use the data in other functions?

Comment: 3th argument should be a pointer to any arbitrary data. Typically some kind of windows context struct with all the relevant fields is created and a pointer to this struct is stored as userdata. It can be retrieved from window handle at anytime.

Comment: My bad, typo. One problem I ran into is that I needed to figure out which buttons the user had checkmarked but I couldn't figure out how to access that information so I just saved the indexes that I knew were checked in a global vector. Could this method be used to alleviate that problem?

Comment: @Colebacha2 You can store that vector as part of each window's context and fetch it when handling button messages.

Comment: Would that look somewhat along the lines of `SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<::LONG_PTR>(vector.push_back(i)));` where this is happening inside the for loop?

Comment: @Colebacha2 No, you should retrieve pointer to that vector as written in my answer and call `push_back` normally.

Comment: I'm sorry SetWindowLongPtrW is starting to confuse me. When I call `SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpter_cast<::LONG_PTR>(strings));`, where is the arbitrary data (strings) being stored? It doesn't appear to be being saved into a variable.

Comment: @Colebacha2 - the data is stored in "extra window memory" that Windows maintains for each hwnd.  It's an old trick to stuff some data away and let Windows track it for you.  (Read:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Colebacha2 `SetWindowLongPtrW` with `GWLP_USERDATA` will only store a *pointer* to arbitrary data. Where this arbitrary data is actually allocated is up to you.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy I gotcha, but since I'll have to be inside the same function to access that data, isn't it kind of pointless? Or is the main point of it to be able to access the data over multiple different calls of the same WndProc function?

Comment: @Colebacha2 It makes it possible to access data from anywhere as long as you have a window handle.

Comment: It seems that I can only get the handle from inside that function though (unless I save it in a global variable). Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Colebacha2 in traditional Win32 "C" programming that is true (Can't think of an exception, anyway).  In C++ you can store it as a class member.  Just be careful that the hwnd is still valid (window not destroyed, for example) before using it.

Comment: BTW, if you are going to do much native Windows programming, look into MFC.  It wraps a lot of this functionality and makes it much easier.  Also look into programming with .NET and C#/VB.Net if you don't "need" a native Windows app.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Couldn't I just completely bypass all this winapi stuff by just using a platform like Qt? And I'd love to dive into .NET and C#/VB once I understand the proper use cases for them.

Answer (score 1):

`lParam` only refers to a `LPCREATESTRUCT` during the `WM_CREATE` message. Other attempts to cast it to that will fail as you described with read access violation. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-create).  Don't attempt to cast it to that type outside of `WM_CREATE`

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you!